# Product expiry date (Unexpected output)

Tags: java, calendar

Greets! I have worked on a following code which was expected to handle the program. If the expiry date given manually by the user is before the current date, program should terminate else program shows how much period is remaining.

When I give input of expiry date as a current date i.e. Year : 2014, Month : 3, Day : 7
To my expectations the program should have terminated but it displays as 1 year etc... remaining. Where am I doing mistake.

```
// Sets GregorianCalendar expiryDate object
static void setTrial(){
    System.out.println("\n----- SET TRIAL DATE ----\n");

    System.out.print("Year : ");
    int year = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();

    System.out.print("Month : ");
    int month = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();

    System.out.print("Day : ");
    int day = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();

    expiryDate = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);
}

// Validates the expiryDate with current GregorianCalendar object
static void validate(){
    System.out.print("\n----- VALIDATING THE PRODUCT ----\n");
    GregorianCalendar current = new GregorianCalendar();

    if( current.after(expiryDate) ){        
        System.out.println("\nYour trial period is expired. Please buy the product.");
    }else{
        GregorianCalendar temp = new GregorianCalendar(expiryDate.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) - 
                        current.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR), 
                        expiryDate.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) - 
                        current.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH), 
                        expiryDate.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - 
                        current.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        System.out.println("\nYou still have " + 
                        temp.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) + " years, " + 
                        temp.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) + " months, " + 
                        temp.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) +
                        " days remaining... \n\nPlease buy the product before it expires!");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following

`expiryDate = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);`

to

`GregorianCalendar expiryDate = new GregorianCalendar(year, month-1, day);`

and

`System.out.println("\nYou still have " + temp.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) + " years, " + temp.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) + " months, " + temp.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + " days remaining... \n\nPlease buy the product before it expires!");`

to

`System.out.println("\nYou still have " + temp.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR-1) + " years, " + temp.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) + " months, " + temp.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + " days remaining... \n\nPlease buy the product before it expires!");`

Answer (score 2):

The months start from 0 (January) to 11 (December).

So you need to do:

```
expiryDate = new GregorianCalendar(year, month-1, day);
```

Also note that the GregorianCalendar has no year 0 (according to the [definition Wikipedia gives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar)), that's why

```
System.out.println(new GregorianCalendar(0, 3, 8).get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR));
```

will print 1.

Instead you can do something like:

```
int yearsRemaining = expiryDate.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) - current.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR);
```